Let T be a bijective bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space H. Assume $T^{-1}$ exists and is bounded. Show that $(T^*)^{-1}$ exists.
This is my current attempt to this problem:
$T^*$ is injective:
I want to show $\mathcal{N}(T*) = \{0\}.$
Consider $T^*(u)=0.$ Then $<T^*(u), v> = 0$ for each $v \in H.$ By the definition of $T^*,$ $<u, T(v)>=0.$ Since $T$ is bijective, every $w \in H$ can be written as $T(v)$ for each $v \in H.$ Therefore, $<u, w>=0$ for each $w \in H$ which allows us to conclude that $u=0,$ as desired.
If this is correct, I have half of the proof complete. However, I am unsure of how to show $T^*$ is surjective. Any advice is appreciated!

It should be easier to just guess what operator is the inverse of $T^*$ and then prove that it indeed is the inverse.

@Matsmir how would I go about doing this given the information I have ($T \in \mathcal{B}(H)$)?

I suggest to write a formula for $(T^*)^{-1}$. Note that you also have the operator $T^{-1}$ at hand.

Let's call $S$ the inverse of $T$, then $S^*$ is the inverse of $T^*$. In fact $\langle v,w\rangle=\langle TSv,w\rangle =\langle v, S^*T^*w\rangle$ and analogously $\langle v,w\rangle=\langle STv,w\rangle =\langle v,T^*S^*w\rangle$ for all $v,w\in H$. This easily implies that $T^*S^*=S^*T^*=\text{Id}_H$, so we are done.
